# Article title showing multiple times in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, foreach, article

**Article title is showing multiple times in foreach loop**

**Here is the articles.php**

```
<?php
    include('functions.php');
    $article = new Article;
    $articles = $article->fetch_all();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample Blog</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="text-center">Articles</h1>   </div>
            <ol>
                <?php
                    foreach($articles as $article){?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $articles["article_id"];?>">
                            <?php echo $articles["article_title"];?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

**And here is the functions.php code**

```
<?php
    require ('config.php');
    if (!$connection) {
        echo "Failed to connect to Server!".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    class Article{
        public function fetch_all(){
            $connection = mysqli_connect(host,username,password,database) or die("Unable to connect to the host");
            $select = "SELECT * FROM articles";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$select) or die(mysqli_error($connection));  
            return (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
        }

    }
?>
```

**Here is the screenshot of the output**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It is because you are selecting all articles, so you will get repeats the way your code is written. Select one article in the query or change your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is within your loop. You are calling `$articles["article_id"]` and `$articles["article_title"]`.
You want `$article["article_id"]` and `$article["article_title"]`.

```
foreach($articles as $article){?>
<li>
    <a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article["article_id"];?>">
        <?php echo $article["article_title"];?>
    </a>
</li>
<?php
}
```

Comment: It say:Warning: Illegal string offset 'article_title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\articles.php on line 20

line20: <?php echo $article["article_title"];?>

Comment: @NoName could you `var_dump($articles)` and post the result please?

Comment: array(4) { ["article_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["article_title"]=> string(11) "Lorem Ipsum" ["article_content"]=> string(94) "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." ["article_timestamp"]=> string(10) "1553116740" }

Comment: is this `$articles` or `$article`? If it's `$articles` then your SQL query does something wrong.

Comment: `foreach($articles as $article_list=>$article){?>
     <li>
      <a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article["article_id"];?>">
      <?php var_dump($article_list)?>
      </a>
     </li>`

Output:
**string(10) "article_id"
string(13) "article_title"
string(15) "article_content"
string(17) "article_timestamp"**

Comment: Outside the foreach, `var_dump($articles)`. The array you get from your query. And edit the result into your answer please. It's hard to read as comment

Comment: [SOLVED]
i just changed 
`return (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));`
to 
`return $result;`
thanks :-)